# PostgreSQL subquery using like

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, select

lets say i have first table like this

**Branch table**

```
|name     |description|
|123456ABC|FOO        |
|553646DEF|FO2        |
```

and second table like this

**Balance table**

```
|name|description|
|ABC |oof        |
|DEF |2of        |
```

i want to query to Balance table, where each row containing name from Branch table..
for example "123456ABC" in Branch table, i want to get "ABC" row from Balance table

how could i achieve that? i've tried this query so far with no luck

```
select * from Balance
where name like (
        SELECT `name` FROM Branch
);
```

any suggestion?

Comment: is it always the last 3 characters or can the name in balance very in length?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should *convert* the `balance`'s names to `LIKE` patterns:

```
SELECT * FROM Balance
WHERE (
    SELECT `name` FROM Branch
) LIKE '%' || name;
```

A join may look more readable:

```
SELECT b.* FROM Balance b JOIN Branch r ON r.name LIKE '%' || b.name;
```

Comment: i used the join method one. Works like a charm! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you will have dupes or not, so you may want to consider using a semi-join.  For large datasets, a semi-join will typically be more efficient than an in-list query.

@clemens solution looks good, assuming no dupes.  Alternatively, you can use regex:

```
select *
from balance ba
where exists (
  select null
  from branch br
  where
    br.name ~ ba.name
)
```

Performance-wise, I think `like` will outperform the regex, but it's an option.

Also, if your string is always at the end, you can consider a join using `right` or `substr`:

```
select *
from balance ba
where exists (
  select null
  from branch br
  where
    right (br.name, length (ba.name)) = ba.name
)
```