# Query for selecting column from one table having text like column in another table

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-like

There are two tables in PostgreSQL
"Public domain" and "Emails" Public domain table has a list of domains in column1 e.g. abcd.com,xyz.com etc..

```
Table-"Public domain"
sr.no domains
1      yahoo.com
2      gmail.com
3      hotmail.com

Table-"Emails"
sr.no  emails
1      abcd@gmail.com
2      efgh@hotmail.com
3      pqr@xyz.com

The query should return:
abcd@gmail.com
efgh@hotmail.com
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PostgreSQL subquery using like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48225313/postgresql-subquery-using-like)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might use `substring` with `position` function [***as***](http://rextester.com/FDL71591) :

```
select e.emails
  from Emails as e
  join PublicDomain as p
    on ( substring(e.emails,position('@' in e.emails)+1,length(e.emails)) = p.domains );

emails
---------------
abcd@gmail.com
efgh@hotmail.com
```

Answer (score 4):

[demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=27337b900f376b7f93a564aeabf0a1ff)

```
SELECT 
    email 
FROM emails e 
JOIN domains d 
ON e.email LIKE '%@' || d.domain
```

Joining the tables against their texts. The normal (`CROSS`) `JOIN` eliminates all rows that are not matching. The matching function is `email LIKE %@domain`. Because `email == something@domain` the join works. `LIKE %@domain` stands exactly for this: "something" and then an `@` and the `domain`.